# sql query performance: finding max

Tags: java, sql, performance

I have a table with group and permission column. I want to find the max permission from a list of group. I am using java and oracle database, I thought of two ways to do this:

Way 1:

```
in java loop through the group list
    result = select permission from table where group = currentgroup
    if result > max, max = result
```

Way 2:

```
max = select max(permission) from table where group in (group list)
```

I thought way 2 would be faster, but then group list can be very long and I dont know if it is a good idea to have long list in a single sql query.

Comment: I don't understand, why should the list length affect the outcome of `MAX()` unless your query is flawed?

Comment: From where do you get this group list? I would assume it comes from your DB. Use an inner join on your groups table. Then you can both do all the work on the DB and not have to provide the entire groups list in the query.

Comment: In oracle there are limits for maximum number of bind variables in a query. Maybe there is a limit for constants also. Anyway I think the bind variable limit is at least 1000. and the constant limit if there is any should be much higher.

Comment: @help: Is you `group list` a variable? If so, then please rewrite it as `group_list` (or whatever), so it doesn't get confused with the `GROUP` keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the information you've given, the second approach is by far the best. Databases are optimised directly for these kinds of tasks, so within reason, its always best to narrow the data down with the database. The first approach means the database needs to return all values anyway, increasing processing time, bandwidth and using up memory within your java application.